# OData "Sequence contains more than one element" error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

> Sequence contains more than one element
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)   at 
>   System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.RemoveBaseTypeProperties(EntityTypeConfiguration derivedEntity, EntityTypeConfiguration baseEntity)
>     at  System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.DiscoverInheritanceRelationships()...

Here's my binding code:

```
var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<PeopleDto>("People");
```

Here's my Controller code:

```
[Queryable]
public IEnumerable<PeopleDto> Get(
        [FromUri] Credentials credentials, 
        ODataQueryOptions<PeopleDto> options, 
        int departmentId,
        DetailLevel detail = DetailLevel.Low)
{
    var count = _repository.Filter(x => x.DepartmentId == departmentId && x.Active);
    options.ApplyTo(count);
    int total = count.Count();

    switch (detail)
    {
        case DetailLevel.Low:
            return new Paginable<PeopleDto>(GetMyPeopleLo(departmentId, options), total);
        // [...]
    }
}
```

`Paginable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. And the `GetMyPeopleLo()` (not the real name) method applies the options to the additional queries. (I don't need additional queries anymore, because I have moved the location of the pagination code, but I just haven't refactored that part yet).

Is this one of those cases where there's an issue with the pre-release version of oData?

*Update:* If I comment out the `Queryable` attribute, it seems to work, but any filter that I specify in the querystring is not actually applied when options are applied to the `count` query.

Comment: That sounds like a problem related to your DTO.

Comment: @SLaks The DTO is a very slim class whose members are all simple types, ints, bools, and strings.

Comment: If I comment out the `Queryable` attribute, it seems to work, but any filter that I specify in the querystring is not actually applied when options are applied to the `count` query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things jump out here:

- You shouldn't be using [Queryable] and ODataQueryOptions. They're used for doing the same thing.
  In this case, ODataQueryOptions seems more appropriate so you should just remove [Queryable].
- You're not using the results of your query. Instead of this

  ```cs
  var count = _repository.Filter(x => x.DepartmentId == departmentId && x.Active);
  options.ApplyTo(count);
  int total = count.Count();
  ```

  You should be writing this:

  ```cs
  var count = _repository.Filter(x => x.DepartmentId == departmentId && x.Active);
  var queryResults = options.ApplyTo(count) as IQueryable<PeopleDto>;
  int total = queryResults.Count();
  ```

  That way your total will take into account the OData query options.
- Consider using `PageResult<T>` instead of Paginable since the OData formatters will take the count and insert it correctly into the OData feed.

Comment: In my version it's still `ODataResult<T>`. I have a question about formatting the URI for the next page result. Is there documentation for this?

Comment: Glad it worked out : ) What's your question? Keep in mind the next page link is optional. There isn't official documentation about this yet because we still haven't released OData support quite yet.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this error in the following two scenarios.

1. Shadowed Entity Members - Members in classes that derive from entities which shadow rather than override (see this [discussion of the difference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172785.aspx)). Swapping to overriding resolved the issue here. Note that I was able to find these by searching within the warnings generated by Visual Studio.
2. Property in entity Partial class of type [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Changing the type of the property to [BitmapSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource(v=vs.110).aspx) (the direct inheritance parent of the BitmapImage) was the fix here.